# Could not create AWS::ECS::Service via cloudformation yaml, got Model validation failed

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

During creation of `AWS::ECS::Service` via cloudformation i got the error: `Model validation failed`

The error is related to `#HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds` and some other properties. Error detail is:  `expected type: Number, found: String`.

In yaml it is already a number. It's not clear to me whats going wrong. Already tried to desclare it as string or as parameter with type Number.

I need some hint because i am stuck in the muck at this point.

Error is:

```
Model validation failed 
    (
    #/HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds: expected type: Number, found: String 
    #/DesiredCount: expected type: Number, found: String 
    #/DeploymentConfiguration/MaximumPercent: expected type: Number, found: String 
    #/DeploymentConfiguration/MinimumHealthyPercent: expected type: Number, found: String
    )
```

Definition in template.yaml is:

```
ServiceDefinition:
  Type: AWS::ECS::Service
  Properties:
    ServiceName: !Ref ServiceName
    Cluster: !Ref ClusterName
    TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
    DeploymentConfiguration:
      MinimumHealthyPercent: 100
      MaximumPercent: 200
    DesiredCount: 1
    HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds: 60
    LaunchType: FARGATE
    NetworkConfiguration:
      AwsVpcConfiguration:
        AssignPublicIP: ENABLED
        SecurityGroups: !FindInMap [Env2SecurityGroups, !Ref AWS::AccountId, securitygroup]
        Subnets: !FindInMap [Env2PublicSubnets, !Ref AWS::AccountId, subnets]
```

Comment: This looks fine. Are you sure this is the resource which gives the errors?

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64327964/cloudformation-yaml-how-to-force-number-type

Comment: I've fixed similar issues by using Amazon's [cfn-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-lint) tool, which does an excellent job of finding schema and type issues.

Answer (score 8):

The error was caused because `SecurityGroups` and `Subnets` resulted in a wrong format.

To extract `subnets` and `securitygroups` the `FindInMap` function was used. It is necessary that this result is a list. This can be achieved using the `Split` function.

The wrong format unfortunately leads to a completely misleading error message.

Declare mappings like this:

```
Mappings
  Env2SecurityGroups:
    '111111111111':
      securitygroup: 'sg-1111111111111111'
    '222222222222':
      securitygroup: 'sg-2222222222222222'
    '333333333333':
      securitygroup: 'sg-3333333333333333'

  Env2PublicSubnets:
    '111111111111':
      subnets: subnet-1111111111111111,subnet-22222222222222222,subnet-33333333333333333
    '222222222222':
      subnets: subnet-1111111111111111,subnet-22222222222222222,subnet-33333333333333333
    '333333333333':
      subnets: subnet-1111111111111111,subnet-22222222222222222,subnet-33333333333333333
```

Use `!Split` combined with `!FindInMap` to get a list:

```
SecurityGroups: !Split [",", !FindInMap [ Env2SecurityGroups, !Ref AWS::AccountId, securitygroup] ]
Subnets: !Split [",", !FindInMap [ Env2PublicSubnets, !Ref AWS::AccountId, subnets] ]
```

Comment: I'm curious how you solved your "expected type: Number" error, as I have the same error for setting up a task definition. It's not clear how this answer relates to the error in the question.

Comment: Actually I think I understand now. It seems the error is misleading. The number conversion actaully is not the cause of the failure. The fault is elsewhere and is reported incorrectly by CF. Just another gotcha with CloudFormation. The error is not nescessarily in any way related to the problem.

Comment: In my case I needed to look further down in the list of errors to find one that makes more sense and that sorts out the misleading error

Comment: I think this might be completely related with the errors but in a different way. The invalid values at some portion of template can cause other side effect which can only be known at runtime. for example when a Import statement returns special characters like uneven quotes, it might corrupt whole file causing unexpected error at runtime

Comment: Same for me. The `expected type: Number, found: String` message is actually a warning, but is displayed as if it was an error. For me, the real error was: `#/ContainerDefinitions/0/PortMappings/0: expected type: JSONObject, found: String`. This happened because I tried to use `!If` to make the PortMappings array entry conditional.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of indentation errors. The error you have posted is just a warning error which didn't cause the failure.
The real reason is you had wrong indentation, which made some fields nested, making it look like a JSON.

If you fix the indentation, your issue should be solved.