# CloudFormation yaml - How to force number type?

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create an ECS task definition as part of a CloudFormation stack.

My task definition so far looks like this...

```
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - EC2
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref MyTaskRole
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Ref ServiceName
          Image: amazon/amazon-ecs-sample
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 3000
              HostPort: 0
              Protocol: tcp
          MemoryReservation: 128
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error...

```
#/ContainerDefinitions/0/MemoryReservation: expected type: Number, found: String
```

So it seems that CloudFormation is converting 128 to a string, and then the stack fails.

What is the correct way to define this value so that it remains a number?

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64246726/could-not-create-awsecsservice-via-cloudformation-yaml-got-model-validation

Comment: What's the full error message of the validation?  Is the `#/ContainerDefinitions/0/MemoryReservation: expected type: Number, found: String`
 the only validation error? 

Mostly it should due to type mismatch.  e.g. use a string for a map or list.

Comment: You may provide your stack Id (or email to (libruce AT amazon.com) so I can help you to see the root cause.

Comment: Thanks @WenbingLi I've actually found the root cause. It was a problem with the logging section definition. I was only able to find this by first removing the MemoryReservation and PortMappings, so it would stop erroneously complaining about the type conversion. After that it showed an error that actually related to the problem.

Comment: I've fixed similar issues by using Amazon's [cfn-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-lint) tool, which does an excellent job of finding schema and type issues.

Answer (score 9):

It turned out that the error that was being reported by CloudFormation actually wasn't anything to do with the failure. The code above was perfectly fine.

In my case the problem was with the way I'd defined the logging section which appeared later in the template.

The takeaway from this, is that CloudFormation is very confusing to debug, and if you receive an error like this, don't assume it is what's actually causing the stack to fail.

To find the actual problem, I had to first remove the properties which were causing the type conversion error, MemoryReservation and PortMappings, and then it showed an error about the way I'd defined my logging section. After fixing that fault, I was able to re-add the other properties, and it worked fine.

I suspect now that because my logging section was incorrect, the whole ContainerDefinitions perhaps wasn't being parsed correctly, potentially causing the misleading type mismatch error.

Comment: For me, the reason was using the [DependsOn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute incorrectly. I had written it under the `Properties` attribute while it should be at the same level as `Properties`.

Comment: @SamkitJain Yes, indent level often catches me out with CloudFormation. I've learned from experience to check for it whenever strange errors occur. Indentation can so easily get messed up when copying and pasting into templates.